# New Methods: Implementing INFINITE LOOP which can be STOPPED upon request

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

**What is the correct method to implement a infinitely running task which executes an *Async* `BigJob()`? and can be stopped upon request**

***Hint***: *I am trying to learn [a] new method(s) to update my existing strategy.*

I have this simple program (a tester) which has an **Start** and **Stop** button.

When **Start** pressed, I am starting the tester which is going to find and test available devices in range and test the hell our of them in ***infinite*** amount of rounds until the user presses the **Stop** button.

The important point is, the main process/action/bigJob() is and awaitble **asynchronous** process.

So I would **pseudo code** the whole thing as

```
Start
  Round 1 starts
    Async Main job starts
       Async connect
       Async Read
       Async Write
       Async disconnect 
    Nobody cancelled me yet
  Round 1 finishes
  Round 2 starts
    .
    .
    .
  Round 2 finishes
  Round 3 starts
    .
    Stop pressed, hence break out. 
Stop
```

So I am using `BackgroundWorker` to implement the infinite loop and `Async/Await` for the *Connect, read, write and disconnect* that I have written in `C#` under `.Net 4.5`

Since my sub-tasks such as **Connect** and .etc are `async` then my main task is `async` and pressing the *Stop* button stops my process since it eliminates the infinite `while` loop that I have with having

```
while (!bw.CancellationPending)
{
    await MainTask();
    ...
}
```

but it doesn't fire the `BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` event, which doesn't do me any harm HOWEVER *it's killing me since the background worker doesn't work as it's supposed to* and I just keep thinking "there should be a better way!".

So, I have been reading about so many new ideas, like why to use `BackgroundWorker` at all now that we have `Async/await`. Some were saying use `Task.Run()` it's magical. I even read recommendations and blogs about this godsend [TPL Dataflow](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow) that I have never heard of. And so far I haven't found a method which is as structured, documented and layed-out as a `BackgroundWorker`. (unless it's such simple or a one liner which doesn't even need documentation or .etc) So, guys, what is the solution for this. Or better way to ask:

**What is the correct method to implement a infinitely running task which executes an *Async* `BigJob()`? and can be stopped upon request**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`CancellationTokenSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But don't pass the `Token` to the `Task.Run` method and don't throw an exception. Simply check if cancellation was requested and then stop.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

Task.Run(
    async () =>
    {
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {              
            await ConnectAsync();
            await ReadAsync();
            await WriteAsync();
            await DisconnectAsync();
        }
    });

cts.Cancel();
```

When you pass a [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the Task itself(`Task.Run(async () => ..., ct)`), you can't use it inside the delegate. It will only cancel the task if cancellation was called **before** the task started running. After it has begun, calling `Cancel` won't have any effect.

Comment: If the cancellation is only for the main loop then it is also better to make the functions synchronous. The main task is async so that takes care of it already.

Comment: @SKall what? which functions? Connect, Read, etc.? If the functions are asynchronous everything should be asynchronous. If they aren't, nothing should be. The OP described them as asynchronous.

Answer (score 8):

Create a [CancellationTokenSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and pass its Token to the async task. This will allow you to signal to your async tasks that cancellation is requested. More info: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873177(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873177%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: So this is how I modified my code into. Correct me if I am wrong. 
I have directed the binding of my **Start** button to an `async` method which uses an awaitable `Task.Run(.., cancellationToken)`. Inside this `Task.Run()` I've put my `while(true)` which stops if the `cancellationToken.ThorwIfCancellationRequest()` triggers in it's first line.

Comment: Doing that will not stop the running task. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23929667/885318

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend everybody to have a read about **three** different methods of [Asynchronous Programming Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the use of the recent and preferred method [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)**
>   Describes the legacy model that uses the IAsyncResult interface to
>   provide asynchronous behavior. This model is no longer recommended for
>   new development.
>
> **Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)**
>   Describes the event-based legacy model for providing asynchronous
>   behavior. This model is no longer recommended for new development.
>
> **Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)**
>   Describes the new asynchronous pattern based on the
>   System.Threading.Tasks namespace. This model is the ***recommended***
>   ***approach to asynchronous programming in the .NET Framework 4 and later***
>   ***versions***.

Thanks to @SKall for pointing me to the right direction.